# RSA Decryption of large numbers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> **Situation:**
>
> In an RSA cryptosystem the public key $(n,e)$ is the pair $(1537,47)$ and the private key, $d$, the prime $7$. Decrypt the message $1451$.

I know to decrypt the message. I would do ${1451}^7\mod{47}$, but how would I find the answer when the number is too large to read of a calculator?

Comment: That's why [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) exists.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, $1451 \equiv 41 \pmod {47}$, so you want $41^7 \pmod {47}$  That is twelve digits, which may fit in your calculator.  Otherwise, do $41^3 =68921 \equiv 19 \pmod {47}$ and you want $19^2\cdot 41 \pmod {47}$ which fits easily.

Added after the update:  you are not reading the question correctly.  The decoding you want is $1451^7 \pmod {1537}$.  You can still do $1451^3=3054936851 \equiv 262 \pmod {1537}$ and proceed as above.  If you calculator is less than $10$ digits, you will need to go through $1451^2$

Comment: Why have you used mod 1537 instead of mod 47?

Comment: Because $n$ is the modulus being used.  $e$ is the encryption exponent.  The message needs to be smaller than $n$.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation) for example

Comment: Ok, so if I do 1451^3 ⋅ 1451^4 mod 1537 then I should get 262 as there is no remainder from 1451^4 mod 1547 and a remainder of 262 from 1451^3.

Comment: I get $1451^4 \equiv 523\pmod {1537}$ per [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1451%5E4+mod+1537)